# CSS - shift long continuous text inside the div to the right?

Tags: css, alignment, right-justified

I have a long text that would not fit within the div it occupies. The div class is as follows:

```
.mydiv {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 5px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Of course I can only see portion of text.  The problem is that it shows first N characters and I want to show last N chars. How do I achieve it with CSS? `Text-align` doesn't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to wrap your text in another element, you can make it work as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XbZ9/).  I've floated a nested `<span>` to the right.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="window">Lots of text</div>
</div>

.wrap { overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
.window { position: absolute; right: 0px; }
```

Comment: Just as a note: float:right as in Pat's example worked for my specific case better

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just CSS:

http://jsbin.com/ususu

```
  <div style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid red; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 2em;">
      <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; padding: .5em;white-space:nowrap;">
  aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiii
     </div>
  </div>
```

(tested in Firefox. YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript to scroll the div all the way to the right, try:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("div-id");
obj.scrollLeft = obj.scrollWidth - obj.clientWidth
```